# multiple if match criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have multiple matching criteria and I'm not sure how to put it all together to get what I'm looking for.

I have a huge data report and I am creating a separate scorecard sheet that only pulls the relevant data. I need the scorecard sheet to first look up and match by a name, then match by a category, then match by 2017 only, and then finally count how many of those instances it found.

so for example: I have 10 employees and want to see how many TV's each employee sold in 2017.

so-look up all rows with last name "jones", then make sure the product column says "tv", next, make sure the date column shows 2017 for that row, and finally, count how many instances were exact matches.

Comment: COUNTIFS() will do it.

Comment: I just tried that and I think the date column is messing it up. all my dates are listed in the (MM/DD/YYYY) format. I tried: (year($k:$k)=2017) for my critera with the criteria_range being the date $k:$k column. 

so: countifs($k:$k,year($k:$k)=2017), etc etc

Comment: To count the year like that you need to braket the dates: `=COUNTIFS(K:K,">=" & DATE(2017,1,1),K:K,"<" & DATE(2017 + 1,1,1),...)`  Where the `...` are your other criteria.

Comment: Another way you can try is this: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A="Jones"),--($B:$B="TV"),--(YEAR($K:$K)=2017))` but don't overdose this formula since it will slow down your spreadsheet.  One field that using it is perfectly okay.